# Extract function outside of main app.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm fairly new to nodejs, and in wanting to keep the code neat and clean, I tried to extract a function to a different file, and then `require` it from my main app.

I'm facing a problem that this function includes `socket-io` data streaming and it uses the `http` module that uses my `express app`

This is the main app, and I want to move the content of `getDetails` to a seperate file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Set router
const router = express.Router();

// fix body of requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/getDetails', (req, res) => {
    const qry = req.query;
    if (qry.func === 'tail') {
        const tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + qry.srv, qry.script, qry.func, qry.serv]);
        io.on('connection', function (socket) {

            tail.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                socket.emit('newLine', {line: data.toString('utf8').replace(/\n/g, '<br>')});
            });
            tail.on('close', (code) => {
                console.log('child process exited with code', code);
            });
            tail.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log('There are some errors:', data.toString('utf8'));
                socket.emit('newLine', {line: data.toString('utf8')});
            });
        });
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
        execFile('ssh', ['root@' + qry.srv, qry.script, qry.func, qry.serv], {timeout: 5000}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('stderr', error);
                return res.status(500).send({stderr: stderr, error: error});
            }
            return res.status(200).send({stdout: stdout.toString('utf8')});
        });
    }
});

app.use('/', router);
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('The magic happens on localhost:' + port);
});
```

Now I can `module.exports` everything on my seperate file but do I need to also require `express`, and `http` again?

And  should I move the `server.listen` to the seperate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const route = require('./route');


// fix body of requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.set('socketio', io);
app.use('/',route);

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('The magic happens on localhost:' + port);
});
```

route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Controller = require('./controller');

router.post('/register',Controller.getDetails);

module.exports=router;
```

controller.js

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;



const controller = {

    getDetails : (req,res)=>{
// now use socket.io in your controller file
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
        const qry = req.query;
    if (qry.func === 'tail') {
        const tail = spawn('ssh', ['root@' + qry.srv, qry.script, qry.func, qry.serv]);
        io.on('connection', function (socket) {

            tail.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                socket.emit('newLine', {line: data.toString('utf8').replace(/\n/g, '<br>')});
            });
            tail.on('close', (code) => {
                console.log('child process exited with code', code);
            });
            tail.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log('There are some errors:', data.toString('utf8'));
                socket.emit('newLine', {line: data.toString('utf8')});
            });
        });
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
        execFile('ssh', ['root@' + qry.srv, qry.script, qry.func, qry.serv], {timeout: 5000}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('stderr', error);
                return res.status(500).send({stderr: stderr, error: error});
            }
            return res.status(200).send({stdout: stdout.toString('utf8')});
        });
    }
    }

}
module.exports=controller;
```

Comment: Thanks! don't I need to export the controller?

Comment: yep... I forgot to add ;)

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: req is not defined` on `io` declaration on the controller @Vicky

Comment: declare io inside getDetails function